# undefined method `comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x58ce72>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, instagram

I keep getting undefined method for 'Comments' it looks everything is fine but no luck here is the code involved

### Models

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :image, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

---

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

end
```

### Controller

```
---Comments Controller----
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    create_notification @post, @comment
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Check the comment form, something went wrong.'
    render root_path
  end
end
```

-----Post Controller involved--------

```
def index
 @post = Post.all
end
```

### View

```
<div class="comment-form">
  <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build ], local:true) do |form| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

### Error

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index
Showing C:/Sites/Womberry2/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #56 raised:
undefined method `comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x58ce720>
Extracted source (around line #56):

    <div class="comment-form">
    <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build ], local:true) do |form| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you please format your code

Comment: and please at the error from log

Comment: jvillian just help me to do that Thank you I am also new at Posting Question at Stack Over Flow

Comment: You don't really say what it is you're trying to do. So, it is hard to know how to help. It looks like you're trying to show all posts on the post index page with a comments form for each post. Did you post this question before? It seems familiar.

Comment: I did not this is my first Post... I trying to connect a Post with the comments I am following a tutorial on that Application i also check ruby guides and there is an example to attach Article to Comments and basically has the same structure that mine but I do not know what is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I had to remove the "@" on the "View" format why?? I do not know but it works now it passed the code without errors

```
<div class="comment-form">
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build ], local:true) do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...' %>
<% end %>
```

it can work without

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

I am putting this so others may be can solve the issue easier than me

Answer (score 0):

In your `index` action, you instantiate `@post` as an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, here:

```
def index
  @post = Post.all
end
```

And, you try to call `comments` on `@post` (an `ActiveRecord_Relation`), here:

```
<div class="comment-form">
  <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build ], local:true) do |form| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But, as the error says, `ActiveRecord_Relation` doesn't respond to `comments`.

BTW, you shouldn't use a singular variable name (`@post`) for a collection such as an `ActiveRecord_Relation`. That's confusing and will cause problems.

Comment: Ok, But do I need to do I am new in rails I am following aTutorial so do I have to change something in my "index action" or "comment-form", thanks for the help.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  accepts_nested_attributes_for to your model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :image, presence: true
  # Here
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

Comment: That will fix `undefined method 'comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x58ce720>`?

Comment: @jvillian He has to follow your answer and use this also

Comment: I just add "accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments" but I am still having "undefined method `comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x5bb8bf8>"